# sliding caption. placing widget div in caption.resizing according to image size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an image with two captions. One will slide down from the top and one will slide up from the bottom. I'd like to get their size relative to the image (so dynamically changing to what ever size the image is) and each of them cover maybe 25% of the image.

At the moment I have one sliding from the left up top but I need it to slide down from the top and the one on the bottom also slides from the left but I need it to slide from the bottom.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4qvL5cf/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>review image system</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.css" />
    <script src="modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="newjavascript.js"></script>
    <script src="toucheffects.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <header>
        <h1 class="main_head">blub</h1>

    </header>
    <hr />

        <div class="container left">

            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="image" />
            <article class="text css3-4">
                    <h1><a href="#" class="css3-4">space1</a></h1>
            </article>
            <article class="text css3-3 css3-4">
                    <h1><a href="#" class="css3-3 css3-4">space2</a>    </h1>
                    <span><div class='movie_choice'>
                                                            <div id="r1" class="rate_widget">
                                                           <div class="star_1 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_2 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_3 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                            <div class="star_4 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                             <div class="star_5 ratings_stars"></div>
                                                             <div class="total_votes">vote data</div>
                                                              </div>
                                                              </div>
                                                    </span>
            </article>
        </div>

    <hr />

    </div>  

    <script>


// first thing added 
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.rate_widget').each(function(i) {
        var widget = this;
        var out_data = {
            widget_id : $(widget).attr('id'),
            fetch: 1
        };
        $.post({
            url:'ratings.php',
            data: out_data,
            success:function(INFO) {
                $(widget).data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            dataType:'json'
        });
    });


    $('.ratings_stars').hover(
        // Handles  mouseover
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_over');
            $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
        },
        // Handles mouseout
        function() {
            $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('ratings_over');
            // can't use 'this' because it wont contain the updated data
            set_votes($(this).parent());
        }
    );


    //  records the vote
    $('.ratings_stars').bind('click', function() {
        var star = this;
        var widget = $(this).parent();

        var clicked_data = {
            clicked_on : $(star).attr('class'),
            widget_id : $(star).parent().attr('id')
        };
        $.post(
                {
            url:'ratings.php',
           data: clicked_data,
            success:function(INFO) {
                widget.data( 'fsr', INFO );
                set_votes(widget);
            },
            dataType:'json'
    });



});

function set_votes(widget) {

    var avg = $(widget).data('fsr').whole_avg;
    var votes = $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes;
    var exact = $(widget).data('fsr').dec_avg;

    window.console && console.log('and now in set_votes, it thinks the fsr is ' + $(widget).data('fsr').number_votes);

    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('ratings_vote');
    $(widget).find('.star_' + avg).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote'); 
    $(widget).find('.total_votes').text( votes + ' votes recorded (' + exact + ' rating)' );
}

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For change slides like you need, you need to change css transitions, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/willianduarte/uv6j5jep/1/)

```
article.css3-3
{
    top:-80px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    width:400px;
}

.container:hover article.css3-3 {
    top:0;
}

...

article.css3-4
{
    bottom:-80px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    width:400px;
}

.container:hover article.css3-4{
    bottom:0;
}
```

I tested remove the width and height properties of the elements ".container". And I think the loaded image will increase the container as needed. [Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/willianduarte/uv6j5jep/3/).

```
.container {
    ...
    /*height: 200px;*/
    ...
}

.container2 {
    ...
    /*height: 200px;*/
    ...
}
```

Comment: @William Duarte That's brilliant, thank you! How would I get the captions and container to scale dynamically to whatever image I use?

Comment: That's kind of what I was looking for but rather than reach each other in the middle I want them to scale to 25% each of the image and the review div that's in the top caption to scale to 50% of the caption and to be positioned in the top left corner. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @William Duarte. I mean the review div to be placed in the top corner of the top caption and by 25% each I mean each caption to take up 25% of whatever image is used. Sorry just thought I should clear that up. Thanks again!!

Comment: Actually sorry you adjusted the image to increase the container so what I need to get now is a way to have the review widget to sit on the top left of the caption. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Dottsie Can you send an example on jsfiddler?

Comment: @Dottsie more or less like this? http://jsfiddle.net/xw3sas7d/1/ in this case you will need adjust the inner elements position

Comment: Perfect thanks very much. Yeah it's the alignment of the inner elements that's getting me. I can't find a good read on it. Thanks for all the help :)